# вставляю данные с помощью openpyxl,но обрезаться данные внутри ячеек из столбца А

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Суть в том что я получаю данные в массив,после я просто прохожусь циклом по excel файлу и определяю где находятся значения которые есть в массиве. После я просто прохожусь по ячейке в которой есть нужное мне значение и ставлю успешно,но при этом у меня обрезается содержимое ячейки которую-то я вообще никак не затрагиваю. Допустим я ставлю успешно в ячейку в колонке L,а информация обращается в той же строке,но в колонке А(именно содержимое этой ячейки обрезается). Возможно есть у кого идеи как это зафиксить ?

Comment: Прошу, предоставьте минимально воспроизводимый код, что бы другие пользователи могли вам помочь

Comment: Чтото я подозреваю, что нужно записывать все значения, а не только новые. Алгоритм такой: сохраняем в переменную все данные из файла, добавляем новые и скопам отправляем всё это на запись. А так получается, что вы новыми данными перезаписываете старые, а сами старые данные уже не записываете

Comment: Суть в том что мне в excel надо добавить только рядом с суммами слово Успех. Зачем мне полностью перезапись делать ?

Comment: @KirillBorisevich вот сейчас когда вы добавляете "успех", старые данные пропадают, верно я вас понял?

Comment: не пришлось бы гадать если бы код был

Comment: @Amgarak они урезаются в соседней ячейке(не по размеру,а по содержимому. Тоесть в соседней строчке было спасибо до написания успешно,а после успешно стало спа

Comment: @videxerion не могу делиться,по правилам места где работаю

Comment: @KirillBorisevich так соберите свой минимально воспроизводящий вашу проблему код, в чем проблема? Если уже работаете программистом то с этой задачей справитесь? Без кода тут можно только гадать...